# Which Belgian beer is served in wooden bowl?

Tags: specialty-beers

I'm sure I had it in the [Delirium Café](http://deliriumcafe.be) in Brussels but I can't remember the name of it.

I have no idea if tastes good as that day was a bit of blur ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only brand of beer I can think of is [Mongozo](http://www.mongozo.com/en/v3/home), which is brewed [in Belgium by a Dutch company (Dutch wikipedia)](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mongozo). They brew various kinds of fruit beers, in addition to a pilsener and a wheat beer.

Comment: That seems very likely to be the one as fruit beers were one thing I remember of that night.